# How to redirect to another page using on keypress in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I need to redirect users using onkeypress in nextjs.

I have a search input where users can type and then press enter key to go to the other page.

##### What I've tried:

```
  const handler = (e) => {
      const ENTER = 13;

      if (e.keyCode === ENTER)  // do a  history.push("/news");
          console.log("enter");
  };

   <input
          onKeyPress={(e) => handler(e)}
          type="text"
          name="search"
          placeholder="Search by keywords"
          className="p-4 md:p-6 w-full  py-2 md:py-4 border-2 text-lg md:text-2xl xl:text-3xl border-gray-400 outline-none filosofia_italic bg-white placeholder-gray-400"
        />
```

i would appreciate your help.

Comment: `location.href = 'http://address.com'`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski — No. That bypasses the client-side routing entirely.

Comment: @Quentin OP didn't say anything about routing

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i used this trick with js and HTML which work well but you know this is JSX and it's a little bit different.

Comment: If you want client-side routing use `react-router-dom` and use `useRedirect` hok from this library.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski — They are using React and tagged the question [tag:next.js].

Comment: @KonradLinkowski — They are using Next.js which has its own router that is not compatible with `react-router-dom`.

Comment: My bad didn't see that tag.

Comment: Hey, sorry about the tag it was made by mistake.

Comment: @Divad — If you aren't using Next.js then what are you using?

Comment: I am using nextjs but i didn't want to write down the nextjs tag cause reactjs and nextjs it's almost the same thing.

Comment: They aren't the same buddy

Comment: @Divad — How you navigate between pages depends on your routing system. React.js does not have a built in routing system. Next.js adds one. If you're asking about routing and using Next.js then Next.js is **highly** relevant.

Comment: @Quentin yes i want for nextjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `useRouter` hook from next - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Try changing you handler to

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router";

const Component = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const handler = (e) => {
    ...
    router.push("/news");
  }

  return (
     <input
       onKeyPress={handler}
       type="text"
       name="search"
       placeholder="Search by keywords"
       className="p-4 md:p-6 w-full  py-2 md:py-4 border-2 text-lg 
       md:text-2xl xl:text-3xl border-gray-400 outline-none 
       filosofia_italic bg-white placeholder-gray-400"
      />
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you forgot to add the keypressing logic. Replace the `...` in the snippet to your logic

Comment: Hi, i did but it doesn't work

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Just nothing but it does console log out when I press enter. i will put the code in the next comment.

Comment: const ENTER = 13;
  const handler = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === ENTER) {
      e.preventDefault();
      router.push("/news");
    }
    console.log("something happened.");
  };

Comment: I think you should put your `console.log` inside of your if statement to see if it ran correctly

Comment: Ok i did it, but now nothing showing in the console.

Comment: @David that means that your if statement doesn't work, and you should change it. I think it is because `e.keyCode` is deprecated - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode. You should use `e.key === 'enter`.

Answer (score 4):

This is [covered by the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/imperatively):

> ## Imperatively
>
> next/link should be able to cover most of your routing needs, but you
> can also do client-side navigations without it, take a look at the
> documentation for next/router.
>
> The following example shows how to do basic page navigations with
> useRouter:
>
> ```
> import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
>
> export default function ReadMore() {
>   const router = useRouter()
>
>   return (
>     <button onClick={() => router.push('/about')}>
>       Click here to read more
>     </button>
>   )
> }
> ```

Comment: Hey, thank you.

Yes, i know about routing, but I need to use keypress which needs to work both on mobile and big resolution too.
and in the search bar, I can't use the router.psuh

Comment: @Divad — There is absolutely no reason that trying to do this inside a keypress event handler, or doing this inside the search bar, would stop you accessing `router.push`. You need to use `router.push` for this.

Comment: @Divad — Supporting `onKeyPress` on mobile *might* cause you problems, but that's a different problem to the one you were asking about. (And one probably solved by using a `onSubmit` event instead.)

Comment: @Divad then there is a problem with your handler function. You need to handle more than just the Enter click event

Comment: @jondoe Yes exactly, even though I tried to do the router. push it doesn't reinsert to another page.

Comment: @Divad which events are you trying to catch? The onKey event won't work on mobile devices

Comment: @jondoe this one>


  const handler = (e) => {
    const ENTER = 13;

    if (e.keyCode === ENTER) {
      router.push("/news");
    }

    console.log("enter");
  };

Comment: I understand that, but that only runs incase a user presses the ENTER key, which mobile devices don't have. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, i made a mistake while asking my question. which I tagged and asked about reactjs, and that's not true, I am using nextjs, but still they are quite the same thing. 

and now what I am trying to do is. to create a search bar when a user searches something and press enter key it should redirect to another page, that's all what I want.

Comment: @Divad — As mentioned above, that's two different problems ((1) Navigating to a different page (which you asked about originally and which this question answered) (2) Detecting enter key presses). Deal with them as separate problems as they are unrelated beyond you wanting to use them together. (And note that I offered a solution to 2 in an earlier comment anyway).

Comment: this solution does something but not the right thing, for example when I start searching it doesn't let me finish typing just redirecting me immediately.

Comment: @Divad — Then something is wrong with how you are testing for the Enter key press.

Comment: @Divad, I think that your should wrap your search bar in an html form, that way when the user presses the enter key then the form would be submitted automatically.

Comment: In nextjs you meant? @jondoe

Comment: In your Nextjs code, try putting the search bar in an HTML form.

Comment: Ok, i did this is the result.

http://localhost:3000/?search=searching+something.

i don't redirect to the other page.